# Resizing kendo tabstrip dynamically to allow scrolling only when width is too large?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I set up my kendo tabstrip like this:

```
$('#filterTabStrip').kendoTabStrip({
                //animation: false,
                animation: {
                    open: {
                        duration: 200,
                        effects: 'expand:vertical'
                    }
                },
                tabPosition: 'top',
                //scrollable: true,
                collapsible: true,
                dataTextField: 'text',
                dataImageUrlField: 'imageUrl',
                dataContentField: 'content',
                select: function(e) {
                    //filterTabStrip-8 is new event tab. If there are no custom buttons, open new event in editor without dropping down tab content.
                    //If there are custom buttons, drop down tab content.
                    if (e.contentElement.id == 'filterTabStrip-8') {
                        //console.log('Creating New Event');  
                        if (webLinksList.length == 0) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#newEventButton').trigger('click');

                            var tabStripTabs = $('#filterTabStrip').data('kendoTabStrip').items();
                            e.sender.deactivateTab(tabStripTabs[7]);
                        }
                    }
                    //filterTabStrip-9 is expand/contract tab
                    if (e.contentElement.id == 'filterTabStrip-9') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //window.open('{!baseUrl}'+'/apex/calendar_test_editor?showHeader=false', 'Full Scheduler View', config='toolbar=no, menubar=no, left=0, top=0');
                        if ('{!showHeader}' == 'true') {
                            window.location.replace('{!baseUrl}' + '/apex/calendar?showHeader=false');
                        } else if ('{!showHeader}' == 'false') {
                            window.location.replace('{!baseUrl}' + '/apex/calendar');
                        } else {
                            window.location.replace('{!baseUrl}' + '/apex/calendar');
                        }

                    }
                    //filterTabStrip-10 and 11 are filter info tabs, and open no content when clicked
                    if (e.contentElement.id == 'filterTabStrip-10' || e.contentElement.id == 'filterTabStrip-11') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }

                },
                dataSource: [{
                        text: '',
                        title: 'User/Resource/Group Filter',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/groups.svg")}',
                        content: $('#user_filter_template').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Custom Picklist Filters',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/picklist.svg")}',
                        content: $('#type_filter_template').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Free Text Filter',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/description.svg")}',
                        content: $('#description_filter_template').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Saved Filters',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/filterList.svg")}',
                        content: $('#filter_select_template').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Download PDF',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/download.svg")}',
                        content: $('#print_pdf_template').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Settings',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/settings.svg")}',
                        content: $('#settingsWindow').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Refresh',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/refresh.svg")}',
                        content: $('#refreshContent').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'New Event',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/add.svg")}',
                        content: $('#addNewEvent').html()
                    },
                    {
                        text: '',
                        title: 'Open Scheduler In Full View Mode',
                        imageUrl: '{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/' + iconName + '.svg")}',
                        content: ''
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Current Saved Filter:\nNone',
                        title: 'Saved Filter',
                        imageUrl: '',
                        content: ''
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Current Users Filtered:',
                        title: 'Users Filtered',
                        imageUrl: '',
                        content: ''
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Where the last two tabs, I dynamically change the text inside based on a filter of users and groups that is a kendo multi-select. In the kendo multi-select change event for this filter, I get all data items, then add each one to the innerHTML of the tabs as appropriate.

My tabstrip will correctly get scroll bars when it reaches the max-width I have set at the width of the viewport. However, when users remove items from the filter, they are removed from the tabs innerHTML, thus shrinking the tab. When it gets smaller than the viewport, the tabstrip does not resize and the side scrollers remain.

How do I best resize the tabstrip so that scroll bars show up when it is larger than the viewport, then disappear when it shrinks below the width of the viewport?

Comment: Can you please set up a demo so we'll have something to work with?

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/EZIza/2 that dojo is what I can come up with at the moment with just about the same initialization, styling, and functionality of my tabstrip. However, in that dojo, the scroll bar appears under the tabs instead of on the sides like it is supposed to :/. Not really sure why it is behaving so annoyingly in the Dojo, but could not get scrollable functionality to work like it is supposed to...

Comment: Can you post an image of the scroll bars you the way you see them in your project (after you've added text)?

Comment: I just figured out why the scroll bar is at the bottom. Removing 'scrollable: true' from the configuration sets up the correct side scrolls for kendo tabstrip, but it has the behavior I specified, where they don't go away when you shrink the tabstrip back to be within the view. I think the link is updated to comment out scrollable: true. That is a kendo bug (it is default true, but setting true breaks it).

Comment: It appears that the class 'k-tabstrip-scrollable' does not get removed from #filterTabStrip even after tab contents are adjusted and the tabstrip is resized...

I am wondering if I just need to get the width of the tabs (because tabstrip is 100% of viewport), but check if the tabs themselves have width less than 100vw to manually remove that class to get rid of those side scrollers?